# Decrease the size of a fraction

Tags: math-mode

I use the following codes

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
  %------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,latexsym,mathrsfs,amsfonts,dsfont}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}                    
%-----accent                        
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  % ------------------------------------------------------------
  \usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
   % ------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{definitions}{Definitions}[section]
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
 \newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
 \numberwithin{equation}{section}
 \begin{document}
 $\displaystyle\lim_{n\longrightarrow\infty}\langle {\bf T} x_n\; 
 |\;x_n\rangle_A=(\frac{1+i}{2},0,0)$
 \end{document}
```

When I compilate I get

[image]

I want to decrease the size of the number (1+i)/2.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\tfrac`, though an inline fraction may be better:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
   \lim_{n\to\infty}\langle \mathbf{T} x_n\mid
   x_n\rangle_A=(\tfrac{1+i}{2},0,0) = ((1+i)/2,0,0)
 \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

I have remove irrelevant packages and improved the coding.  Note in particular,

- `\to` instead of `\longrightarrow`
- `\mathbf{T}` instead of `{\bf T}`
- `\mid` instead of `\;|\;`

Comment: tank you very much for your help. What are the necessary packages for mathematical papers? I use the following: \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,latexsym,mathrsfs,amsfonts,dsfont}

Comment: @Student That is a reasonable selection of packages, but it depends exactly what type of mathematics constructs you need - look up their documentation either on ctan.org or via `texdoc ...` to see what they do.  Also remember the `mathtools` package that extends `amsmath`.

Comment: ... which can be loaded in the place of `amsmath`, since it loads it.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks you. I mean what are the necessary mathematical packages for a standard mathematical papers?

Comment: @Student There is no fixed standard list of such packages - mathematicians keep inventing new notation...

Answer (score 4):

Some improvements and suggestions: loading `mathtools` and `xparse`, one can define an `\innerp` command, which displays an inner product  typeset in a ‘natural’ way: both arguments are grouped and separated by a comma. The delimiters can be adjusted automatically to the contents with the `\innerp*` command, or manually with an optional argument: `\big,\Big,\bigg` or `\Bigg`.

In addition, I loaded the `nccmath` package, which defines medium-sized commands (~ 80% of `\displaystyle`), among which `\mfrac`, often looking better than `\tfrac`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\innerp}[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{\innpargs{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargs}{ >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m }
 {\innpargsaux#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\innpargsaux}{ m m }
 {#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2}%\;\delimsize\vert\;

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
   \lim_{n\to\infty} \innerp[\big]{\mathbf{T}x_n, x_n}=\Bigl(\mfrac{1 + i}{2},0,0\Bigr)=\Bigl(\mfrac{1}{2}(1 + i),0,0\Bigr)
 \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, according to your answer, mathtools can replace amsmath?

Comment: It doesn't exactly replace amsmath, it's an extension, and loads it, so needless to load it twice.